# make aliases for the !history commands

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make aliases for `!num` type commands. Really, just the format is good enough. My goal is to functionally have history wrap around.

Basically, if my `HISTSIZE` is 150, and my command number is 175, then `history` will output things from 26 on, meaning `!11` returns `-bash: !11: event not found`.  I want to make it so I can alias `!num` to `!(num+something)` if `!num` would return `event not found`.

I tried

```
alias x='!$1 || !(( $1 + 100 ))'
```

to use `x` instead of `!` because I guess I don't really care if it's that specific character, but `x11` isn't a command and `x 11` returns `!: command not found` and then `a.txt: command not found` which came from the first file in my current directory.

I also tried

```
j:~$ !$(echo 180)
)(echo 180)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
j:~$ !(( 100 + 80 ))
-bash: !: event not found
j:~$ eval "!(( 100 + 80 ))"
bash: a.txt: command not found...
```

so I'm not sure that getting `!` to take any number that's not immediately typed after is even possible.

EDIT: I am aware I was using positional arguments with aliases incorrectly, and that I should have used a function instead. I will make a function using `fc` to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to use `!` use the `fc` command.

```
fc -s $((100-80))
```

will run the same command as `!20`

Comment: This gives me enough information that I should be able to do what I want. Thank you.